# bonfire codeigniter chaining model methods

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm just a newbie to bonfire / ci.  I am trying to recreate the following sql statement by chaining bf/ci model methods:

```
        SELECT  prod_cat.cat_id, 
                prod_cat.prod_id, 
                prod.enabled, 
                prod.name,
                prod.prod_id,   
        FROM prod_cat, prod 
        WHERE prod.is_enabled = 1 
        AND prod_cat.cat_id =15 
        AND prod_cat.prod_id = prod.prod_id 
        ORDER BY prod.name DESC
```

I have a bf / ci prod_model and a prod_cat_model.

I know that I can do the following to get all prods that match cat_id 15, for example:

```
 $this->load->model('cat/prod_cat_model');  
 $records = $this->prod_cat_model->find_all_by('cat_id' => $cid);
```

Similarly, I plan to use the find_all_by on the product table to limit to records that are active / enabled, like so:

```
 $this->prod_model->find_all_by('enabled', 1);
```

To start, as a test, I was thinking of trying to combine these two tidbits of code by passing an array to the prod_model like so:

```
  public function productsincategory($cid)
  {
    $this->load->model('cat/prod_cat_model');   
    $criteria = array(
    'enabled' => 1,
    'prod_id' => $this->prod_cat_model->find_all_by('cat_id', $cid)
    );
    $records = $this->prod_model->find_all_by($criteria) ;
  }
```

I'm getting an error message:

> Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'
>
> SELECT * FROM (`prod`) WHERE `enabled` = 1 AND `prod_id` = Array

which makes sense... but I don't know how to fix it so that it's something like "select * from prod where enabled = 1 and prod_id in (prod ids from prod_cat table)
I've also tried to use "where_in()" but that doesn't seem to be recognized by bonfire.
Thanks.

Comment: have you tried using php-activerecord sparks? You don't need to have queries on each model. For products and categories, you just need Category::find(1)->include('products'). Of course you have to set up the relationships on the models.

Answer (score 0):

I created my own where_in() method in my product model, like so:

```
public function where_in($field=NULL, $value=NULL)
{
    if (!empty($field))
    {
        if (is_string($field))
        {
            $this->db->where_in($field, $value);
        }
        else if (is_array($field))
        {
            $this->db->where($field);
        }
    }

    return $this;

}//end where()
```

and so in my controller, i do something like this:

```
  public function productsincategory($cid)
  {
    $this->load->model('cat/prod_cat_model');  
    $this->prod_cat_model->where('cat_id', $cid);
    $records = $this->prod_cat_model->find_all();

 $prod_ids = array();

foreach($records as $record)
{
    array_push($prod_ids, $record->product_id);
}

    $this->prod_model->where_in('prod_id', $prod_ids) ; //call our own where_in method
$records = $this->prod_model->find_all();
  }
```